# How to clone millions of copy of a database model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a custom **User** model in django. Some other models are related to that user model like **UserDetails, Prlofile** etc.

Now I need on around 100k users in my database for a testing purpose.

I just wanna create users by changing tehir email address which is in User model.

What is the best way to create suchc a large number of objects and save it to database also with corresponding related models.

Answer (score 0):

download a few thousand names in a file and code something, that will just add the name@gmail.com, name@email.com, name@whateveryouwant.com, and with the name, just make it nameRANDOMNUMBERS, same for the password. It will take time to get 100k, but I'm not sure, if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a script and run it once like so:

```
import names
from . import YourModel

# Create the loop
for n in range(100000):

    # Assign random name
    username = names.get_full_name()

    # Assign random mail address
    email = username + '@gmail.com'

    # Write the new entry to your database table
    obj, created = YourModel.objects.update_or_create(
                                    defaults={
                                        'username': username,
                                        'email': email,
                                    }
```

This should be fairly enough for your needs. Otherwise you could extend this basic example as required like inserting a list of multiple mail-addresses etc.
You can copy the above idea to use for your other models as well.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, it's the easiest way to do it

```
from .models import YourModel


for n in range(100000):
    username, email = f'username{n}', f'email{n}@email.com'
    YourModel.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
```

Comment: the op asks what is the best way not the easiest !

Comment: @Adam, 100k records for test, so what's the problem?